# Detect support for -webkit-filter with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, filter, webkit

Using JavaScript, how do you detect if a browser supports webkit filters?

Based on the info provided at [Default CSS filter values for brightness and contrast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758007/default-css-filter-values-for-brightness-and-contrast), I have tried the following and a few of the other default values:

```
 if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("( -webkit-filter:opacity(1) )").matches) {
 alert("supported");
 }else{
 alert("not supported");
 }
```

Comment: Have a look-see at this site, you may find what you're looking for: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047206/how-can-i-feature-detect-css-filters

Answer (score 7):

An relatively easy way to test whether a css property is supported is the following:

1. Create an element
2. Apply the CSS in question to the element
3. Read the value - if it is the same value you set in step 2, it is supported, otherwise not

js:

```
var e = document.querySelector("img");
e.style.webkitFilter = "grayscale(1)";
if(window.getComputedStyle(e).webkitFilter == "grayscale(1)"){
   "supported!";
}
```

[see the Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cj8vr/2/)